# Python format output in concise manner

Tags: python

Is there any conciser way to express:

```
'{:f};{:f};{:f};{:f};{:f}'.format(3.14, 1.14, 2.14, 5.61, 9.80)
```

such that one does not need to write{:f} multiple times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use any nice way you can think of to generate the string, for example using `join`:

```
';'.join(['{:f}' for _ in range(5)]).format(3.14, 1.14, 2.14, 5.61, 9.80)
```

Here's another variation with the format inside the list comprehension. This is nice because it doesn't require typing the length of the list.

```
nums = [3.14, 1.14, 2.14, 5.61, 9.80]
';'.join(['{:f}'.format(n) for n in nums])
```

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by figs's answer (upvoted):

```
('{:f};'*5).format(3.14, 1.14, 2.14, 5.61, 9.80)[:-1] # strip the trailing semicolon
```